# Can I use dokku predeploy to install google chrome in a docker container?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, dokku

I need to install google chrome in a container and make it accessible to any user that is running the container. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Dokku plugin for that!

https://github.com/lazyatom/dokku-chrome